# How to delete a firebase user using uid?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have an admin web app. I want to delete users by passing uid. Is it possible using flutter with firebase? Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

With the Client SDKs you can only delete your own user account.

If you want to delete user by passing uids you need to use one of the [Admin SDKs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users), either from a server you control or through a Cloud Function.

For example, you could call, from your app (web, Flutter, iOS or Android), a [Callable Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable) that would delete the given user.

The following simplified Cloud Function code would do the trick:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();

exports.deleteUser = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {

    try {
        // Potentially verify that the user calling the CF has the right to delete users

        await admin.auth().deleteUser(data.uid);
        return { result: 'user successfully deleted'};
    } catch (error) {
        throw new functions.https.HttpsError(...)   // See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#handle_errors
    }

});
```

---

You'll find [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable#call_the_function) how to call it from a Web app and [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_functions/latest/) from a Flutter app.